# Not able to divide each row of a csv file in the form of array using perl

Tags: arrays, perl, csv

I am stucked in a problem wherein I am parsing a csv file. The CSV file looks like-

```
CPU Name,DISABLE,Memory,Encoding,Extra Encoding
,b,d,,
String1,YES,1TB,Enabled,Enabled
String2,NO,1TB,Enabled,Enabled
String3,YES,1TB,Enabled,Enabled
```

I want to capture the first two rows in two different arrays. The code that I am using to do it is-

```
my $row_no =0;
while(my $row=<$fi>){
chomp($row);
$row=~ s/\A\s+//g;
$row=~s/\R//g;
#say $row;
if($row_no==0)
{
    #say $row;
    my @name_initial = split(',',$row);
    say length(@name_initial);
    say @name_initial;
}
elsif($row_no==1)
{
    #say $row;
    @data_type_initial =split(',',$row);
    say length(@data_type_initial);
    say @data_type_initial;
}
$row_no++;
}
```

Now I formed two arrays from topmost two lines in file (@name_initial and @data_type_initial respectively).When I am printing these array I can see all the 5 values but when I am printing the length of array it is showing length of each array as 1. When I am printing the element using index of arrays I find each element in place then why it is showing length as 1. Also second array which is formed from second line of csv file is printed as "bd". All the null values are gone and although it is containing two values 'b' and 'd'. Its length is printed as 1.

I want to convert the row of csv file in array with all the null and non_NULL values so that I can iterate on the array elements and can give conditions based on null and non null values.How can I do that???

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [perldoc length](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html). It says this:

> **length EXPR**
>
> **length**
>
> Returns the length in *characters* of the value of
>   EXPR. If EXPR is omitted, returns the length of `$_`. If EXPR is
>   undefined, returns `undef`.
>
> This function cannot be used on an entire array or hash to find out
>   how many elements these have. For that, use `scalar @array` and `scalar
>   keys %hash`, respectively.
>
> Like all Perl character operations, length normally deals in logical
>   characters, not physical bytes. For how many bytes a string encoded as
>   UTF-8 would take up, use `length(Encode::encode('UTF-8', EXPR))` (you'll
>   have to `use Encode` first). See Encode and perlunicode.

In particular, the bit that says "This function cannot be used on an entire array or hash to find out how many elements these have. For that, use `scalar @array` and `scalar keys %hash`, respectively".

So you're using the wrong approach here. Instead of `say length(@array)`, you need `say scalar(@array)`.

To explain the results you're getting. `length()` expects to be given a scalar value (a string) to measure. So it treats your array as a scalar (effectively adding an invisible call to `scalar()`) and gets back the number of elements in the array (which is "5") and `length()` then tells you the number of elements in that string - which is 1.

It's also worth pointing out that you don't need to keep track of your own `$row_no` variable. Perl has a built-in variable called `$.` which contains the current record number.

Using that knowledge (and adding little whitespace) gives us something like this:

```
while (my $row = <$fi>) {
  chomp($row);

  $row =~ s/\A\s+//g;
  $row =~s/\R//g;

  #say $row;

  if ($. == 0) {
    #say $row;
    my @name_initial = split(/,/, $row);
    say scalar(@name_initial);
    say @name_initial;
  } elsif ($. == 1) {
    #say $row;
    @data_type_initial = split(/,/, $row);
    say scalar(@data_type_initial);
    say @data_type_initial;
  }
}
```

**Update:** You sneaked a couple of extra questions in at the end of this one. I'd suggest that you raise those separately.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.The second array when I am printing using scalar is giving count as 3. It should give 5 (including NULL and non_NULL values) Why It is giving count as 3. Do you have some idea??-@Dave Cross

Comment: @rikki: Yes, I have an idea. If you read the [documentation for `split()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), you'll see that it actually takes three arguments and the third one (the limit) is optional and, in fact, rarely used. If the limit is omitted then trailing empty fields are dropped from the list returned by the function. You could explicitly give it a limit of 5, but a more flexible solution would be to use -1 (as then `split()` splits into the maximum number of fields and doesn't drop empty ones).

Comment: @rikki: There's a lot of very good documentation available for Perl. But it's all a bit of a waste if people don't read it :-)